# React-Native navigation unable to resolve module

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am getting an error that @react-navigation/native could not be found within the project. I tried to install it and my package.json file says. I am not sure what to do next to get it running. Cheers `{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.5.1",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}`

Comment: How are you testing? IOS or android? Did you do pod install?

Comment: Did you try to run: `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Answer (score 0):

I get that problem sometimes as well, when I restart the app the problem is gone. I don't know why it happens, though.

Comment: I tried to restart the app a couple of times and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Did you try to disconnect and reconnect from the development server?

Comment: Yep, but it didn't help unfortunately